# Angular: Parse $index before parsing full variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a angular form where i need to pass the $index of an ng-repeat back to the controller to make sure i am displaying the correct message. Here is the markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <form name="form_{{$index}}">
    <input name="UserName" ng-model="user.name" ng-required="true">
    <div id="error-message" ng-show="form_{{$index}}.$error.required">
    {{form_{{$index}}.$error.message}}
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In the controller the data may look like this if the index were to be 2:

```
form[2].$error.required = true;
form[2].$error.message = Form field is required;
```

The problem is i can't put `{{$index}}` inside the `{{form_{{$index}}.$error.message}}` because it creates an angular error:

[Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax)

For the end results i would like: `form_{{$index}}.$error.message` to be parsed into `form_2.$error.message` which in turn will be parsed into `Form field is required`

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Here is a pen on this issue: [CodePen Angular Form Repeat Issue](http://codepen.io/jacob-king/pen/XmdzrK?editors=101)

Comment: Why not trying `{{form[$index].$error.message}}` if form is an array of objects?

Comment: can't nest `{{}}` expressions

Comment: I did a little bit of debug and it seems that your custom directive is actually never executed and that is due to the fact that you never reference to your directive in the codepen example.

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen an inconvenient way to name your form and later attempt to access it. There is no reason to have a dynamic form name (which, sets the scope property of the same name) inside `ng-repeat`, since you will already have the benefit of a child scope per iteration.

The following would achieve the result that you are after, without using a dynamic form name:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <form name="userForm">
    ...
    <span ng-show="userForm.$error.required">
      error
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

But, if you insist, you could use `this` to refer to scope, which allows you to refer to its property like so:

```
<span>{{this['form_' + $index].$error.required}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the input to be

```
<input name="UserName" type="text" custom-validation ng-model="user.name" ng-required="true">
```

than the directive gets executed and if you change the form name to something static, than your message gets displayed.
Here is a working example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MayOBJ?editors=101.